# Как порезать string

Tags: c++, строки

Как можно порезать `string` формата:

```
Haljii Ye Kei M 33 3400$
```

так, чтобы можно было сортировать подобные строки по числовому значению? В данном случае по `33`.

Один из вариантов - порезать строку, поместить в массив и по нужному индексу сортировать строки. Но как порезать строку в *с++* я не знаю. Подскажите, как можно реализовать эту задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно поделить строку `str` на подстроки, используя в качестве разделителя `delimiter` (по дефолту — пробел), вернется вектор с подстроками:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>  

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &str, char delimiter)
{

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::stringstream sstr(str);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(sstr, token, delimiter)) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, выручил! :)